# Restart loop on dual boot system after booting Windows

Tags: dual-boot, restart

I have a desktop computer, MOBO: asus z270-p. SSD-500GB.

I installed windows 10 64-bit, LTSB, and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

It worked until I logged into Windows for the first time. After that, upon restart, the computer is getting stuck at a loop, before even getting to GRUB.

I tried repairing grub; and reinstalling Ubuntu, and again observed the same phenomena - it works up until the first Windows login.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: do you have "Fast Startup" disabled in windows?

Comment: i did, but i disabled it.
edit: in bios i mean, do you mean inside windows?

Comment: I mean in windows. Disabling fast boot in BIOS only serves to give you more time to hit function keys at boot to get into BIOS.

Comment: No. I checked, and its off

Comment: If on an UEFI system in BIOS make sure Ubuntu is selected as boot option and not Windows. Selecting Ubuntu EFI in BIOS will give you grub menu where you can select dual boot options. At least that's how it works on my BIOS.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have this option on my bios

Comment: Anyone has more ideas?